# How to make sure there is a 1:1 pixel/texel ratio for a texture

Tags: c++, direct3d

I want to use Direct3D to display a texture on screen, not only that I want it to cover the whole window, but I want to be the actual size of the texture (i.e. every pixel on the screen to be mapped on one texel from the texture)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a texture with the same screen width and height and a fullscreen quad.

You can also scale the texture, but this is only a bad fix because you make it 1:1 pixel/texel but the quality goes down.

Maybe this will help: [Rendering full-screen quads](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/513376-rendering-full-screen-quads/)